# Can't send embeds in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I try to send an Embed to a TextChannel:

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Some title')

msg.channel.send(embed);
```

It just gives me this error:

```
(node:76224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: fields.flat is not a function
    at Function.normalizeFields (C:\Users\user\Desktop\code\jbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:450:8)
    at MessageEmbed.setup (C:\Users\user\Desktop\code\jbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:78:91)
    at new MessageEmbed (C:\Users\user\Desktop\code\jbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:18:10)
    at embedLikes.map.e (C:\Users\user\Desktop\code\jbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\APIMessage.js:166:40)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at APIMessage.resolveData (C:\Users\user\Desktop\code\jbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\APIMessage.js:166:31)
    at TextChannel.send (C:\Users\user\Desktop\code\jbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:166:62)
    at Object.module.exports.execute (C:\Users\user\Desktop\code\jbot\commands\help.js:36:17)
    at Client.client.on.message (C:\Users\user\Desktop\code\jbot\index.js:38:42)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
(node:76224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:76224) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have the latest version of discord.js. And I have also tried to reinstall discord.js but it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update NodeJS to at least version 12, that'll solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

First use the lastest version of Node.JS ( I use 14 ),

Use That

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
   console.log(`${client.user.tag} I am here!`);
});
client.on("message", async message => {  // If no want to use async delete it
   if(message.content === ".embed") {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      embed.setTitle("This is a embed!")
      embed.setDescription(`That is an embed [https://stackoverflow.com](StackOverFlow)`)
      embed.addFields(
            { name: "FIeld Name", value: "true inline", inline: true }
            { name: "Field Name", value: "true inline", inline: true }
            { name: "FIeld Name", value: "false inline", inline: false }
            { name: "Field Name", value: "false inline", inline: false }
      )
            embed.setFooter("Footer Name")
            embed.setAuthor("options")
            embed.setImage("image_Link");
            await message.channel.send(embed);  // If you are not using async delete await
}
});
```

**Have Fun with your Bot!**

This only work on Discord.JSv12
To install it type in your cmd / linux terminal `npm install discord.js@v12`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fix the problem by using EmbedBuilder instead of MessageEmbed. You can find the documentation link below. https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview

Example:

```
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle('Some title')

channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
```

Answer (score -1):

***First Install The Node.js & Discord.js Latest Version And Write The Code!***

```
const discord = require("discord.js") //i define discord.js

const your embed name = new discord.MessageEmbed()

.setTitle()
.setDescription()

msg.channel.send(embed);
```

***and any question you can ask me i am free***

Answer (score -2):

Please make sure that your node.js version is at least v12. This will most likely solve your problem. If you are using ubuntu, here is a guide on upgrading to v12:

[guide](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-nodejs-on-ubuntu-debian-linux-mint/)

Step 4 is skippable

Comment: How is this a better response than the approved one. And by checking the error message, you can see that OP is using Windows, not Ubuntu.